# add object values to a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I am storing an applicants text box data in a session class. I am calling the session class and storing it in an object.

How can i loop through the items, and add them to a database?

Can i loop through and concatenate into a string? I am using a data access layer and an oracle database.

Here is the string for the insert in the DAL. I dont have the function complete since i dont know what to pass in at this point. But, i do have a runquery function that works that i pass the string sql into.

```
public void AddJobApplication()
{
string sql = "insert into JOBQUESTIONS (JOBAPPLICATIONID, QUESTIONTEXT, TYPEID, HASCORRECTANSWER, CORRECTANSWER, ISREQUIRED) VALUES (" + JobID + ", \'" + QuestionText + "\', " + TypeID + ", " + HasCorrectAnswer + ", \'" + CorrectAnswer + "\', " + IsRequired + ")";
 RunQuery(sql);
```

}

Here is my session class

```
public class JobApplicantSession
{

    public JobApplication ApplicationSession
    {

      get {if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"] != null)
               return (JobApplication)HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"];
           return null; }

      set{ HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"] = value; }
    }


}
```

Then, i can retrieve that session and store it in an object

```
JobApplicantSession _sessions = new JobApplicantSession();
JobApplication _application;
_application = new JobApplication(jobID);
_sessions.ApplicationSession = _application;   //_application holds all my saved textbox texts

JobApplication application;

var jas = new JobApplicantSession();
application = jas.ApplicationSession;   //holds all my session text
```

I want to insert multiple records in table JOBQUESTIONS  and i have all these records in the application variable

Thank you!!!

Comment: I think you cant concatenate you have to run a loop and insert each answer to their respective question id

Comment: Do you want to insert multiple records in table JOBQUESTIONS ? and you have all these records in the _session variable ?

Comment: @Habib Yes thats what i want to do. How would i go about looping through the object? its complaining about 'GetEnumerator'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things: 
First its seems that `JobApplication` is an object which is holding data for a particular job application. You can't do iteration on that. You probably need a list of JobApplication and your object application should be something similar to 
`List<JobApplication> applications = new List<JobApplication>();` 
You can only iterate using foreach through an object if it has Ienumerable interface implemented. (Generally speaking an Array of objects or List of Objects)

For inserting data in database, once you were able to iterate and construct a query, I would recommend building a single insert statement with multiple values. Then call it once to insert data in database. Please do take care of [SQL Injection](http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/tutorial/SQLInjection/index.htm). Also if you think that using multiple insert statements suits your need then use a [transaction](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18007/Processing-with-C-Oracle-Transactions-and-Oracle-E)

Comment: How would i do this? "For inserting data in database, once you were able to iterate and construct a query, I would recommend building a single insert statement with multiple values."

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly instead of concatenating parameters, it will be better to use parameterized queries since currently you are open to an SQL injection attack. This article could get you started on that : http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson06.aspx
2. Pass JobApplication object tp SQL function (or if needed a collection of it in the form of List or array,) you can loop through each record and run insert queries against it. It's a performance concern in the sense that you are hitting database more than once. But if your application is small then it's not a major issue. There are ways to send the insert for more than one record in one go using something like Dataset but that might be a little advance for you currently, so if you don't have to look into it then I would suggest to just loop through your JobApplicationCollection.

Comment: I tried to loop through the object but its complaining about 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: foreach (var o in application)

Comment: and what's the type for application ?

Comment: You cannot run foreach loop on JobApplication object, you need to use a List or array object and the defniition should go like : List<JobApplication> applications = new List<JobApplication>();